HDR to SDR Full Convertion
How do I fully convert HDR videos/movies to SDR? Meaning, the output SDR will have all the colors from the HDR input? Is that even possible?
Will this do the trick?
ffmpeg -i INPUT -vf zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=clip,zscale=transfer=bt2020,format=yuv420p OUTPUT
Here's the information of my movie:
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5@Main
HDR format                               : SMPTE ST 2086, HDR10 compatible
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 1 h 55 min
Bit rate                                 : 5 910 kb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 1 600 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.40:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.040
Stream size                              : 4.76 GiB (42%)
Writing library                          : x265 3.1+11-de920e0a3183:[Windows][GCC 9.1.1][64 bit] 10bit
Encoding settings                        : rc=crf / crf=16.0000 / qcomp=0.60 / qpstep=4 / qpmax=69 / qpmin=0 / no-lossless / no-cu-lossless / ipratio=1.40 / pbratio=1.30 / aq-mode=4 / aq-strength=1.00 / psy-rd=2.00 / psy-rdoq=1.50 / rdoq-level=2 / cbqpoffs=0 / crqpoffs=0 / ctu=64 / min-cu-size=8 / ref=4 / limit-refs=3 / limit-modes / me=3 / subme=3 / merange=57 / no-hme / rd=4 / no-rd-refine / no-ssim-rd / rdpenalty=0 / deblock=0:0 / min-keyint=23 / keyint=250 / bframes=4 / bframe-bias=0 / b-adapt=2 / no-b-intra / b-pyramid / cutree / max-merge=3 / no-fades / weightp / no-weightb / rect / no-amp / sao / no-limit-sao / no-sao-non-deblock / no-early-skip / no-splitrd-skip / rskip / no-tskip / no-tskip-fast / no-fast-intra / scenecut=40 / scenecut-bias=0.00 / rc-lookahead=35 / gop-lookahead=0 / lookahead-slices=4 / max-tu-size=32 / tu-inter-depth=1 / tu-intra-depth=1 / limit-tu=0 / qg-size=32 / radl=0 / open-gop / no-hevc-aq / no-aq-motion / no-dynamic-refine / dynamic-rd=0.00 / nr-intra=0 / nr-inter=0 / strong-intra-smoothing / no-constrained-intra / no-strict-cbr / no-const-vbv / no-rc-grain / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / signhide / stats-write=0 / stats-read=0 / zone-count=0 / input-csp=1 / input-res=3840x1600 / interlace=0 / total-frames=165883 / frame-threads=4 / level-idc=0 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / no-analyze-src-pics / no-allow-non-conformance / repeat-headers / annexb / aud / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / temporal-mvp / no-temporal-layers / no-splice / no-intra-refresh / sar=0 / overscan=0 / videoformat=5 / range=0 / colorprim=9 / transfer=16 / colormatrix=9 / chromaloc=0 / display-window=0 / master-display=G(8500,39850)B(6550,2300)R(35400,14600)WP(15635,16450)L(10000000,1)cll=1000,167 / min-luma=0 / max-luma=1023 / log2-max-poc-lsb=8 / vui-timing-info / vui-hrd-info / slices=1 / no-opt-qp-pps / no-opt-ref-list-length-pps / no-multi-pass-opt-rps / no-opt-cu-delta-qp / hdr / hdr-opt / no-dhdr10-opt / no-idr-recovery-sei / analysis-reuse-level=5 / scale-factor=0 / refine-intra=0 / refine-inter=0 / refine-mv=0 / refine-ctu-distortion=0 / refine-analysis-type=0 / ctu-info=0 / copy-pic=1 / max-ausize-factor=1.0 / no-single-sei / no-svt / no-field / no-lowpass-dct / cpuid=1049071 / numa-pools=12,12 / log-level=2 / qp-adaptation-range=1.00
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
Mastering display color primaries        : BT.2020
Mastering display luminance              : min: 0.0001 cd/m2, max: 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Content Light Level              : 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Frame-Average Light Level        : 167 cd/m2


When you ask whether this will do the trick, have you tried that? It seems it would be easy enough to check, and so we ask whether you have. HDR is more about conveying additional information to display panels that support a not-yet universal feature: a wider contrast range (I believe). I don't believe it is about the actual colors of the signal, though in seeing the difference between panels that do and do not support HDR, the wider CONTRAST spread may also APPEAR to result in unique colors.

Does this answer your question? FFMPEG 4k HDR to 1080p SDR Hardware Tonemap Conversion ( OpenCL)

See also here: https://superuser.com/questions/1813336/hdr-to-sdr-conversion-with-ffmpeg

I'm not asking that. I'm asking if it's possible to fully convert HDR colors to SDR without any color loss.

If you're asking whether it's going to LOOK the same, the answer is "no". But, going back: What happened when you tried that command? If you haven't tried it, please do that.
